# Transformation of random variables that preserves the distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Suppose we have a random variable $X$ with distribution $F_X$.
Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two independent copies of $X$.

> **My question:** can we find a transformation $Z=g(X_1,X_2)$ such that the distribution of $Z$ is given by $F_X$?

For example, if $X$ is a standard normal then such a transformation is given by $g(X_1,X_2)=0.25 X_1+0.25X_2$.

Another example is we have $X={-1,1}$ equally likely. Then the transformation is  $g(X_1,X_2)=X_1X_2$.

Note, a  trivial answer to this question is $g(X_1,X_2)=X_1$. 
However, I would like to find something more interesting.

I started with the usual set up but didn't get anywhere
\begin{align}
F_Z(z)=\mathbb P [ g(X_1,X_2) \le z]
\end{align}

Comment: If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent standard normal random variables, then $0.5X_1+0.5X_2$ has zero mean but variance $(0.5^2+0.5^2=0.5$, no?  You would have better luck with $X_1\cos\theta+X_2\sin\theta$.

Comment: As said, you may look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution in which the linear combination of independent random variables will be again in the same family, up to location and scale parameter changes.

Comment: @DilipSarwate thank I made a mistake. Corrected now.

Comment: @BGM this is related to what I am searching for. The class of stable distribution is something that is stable under linear transformations. The goal here is to find a transformation for a given distribution such that the stability under this transformation is preserved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We give a very weak result: sometimes the only functions $g$ are the trivial ones. Let $X$ take on values $0$ and $1$, and let $\Pr(X=1)=p$, where $p$ is *transcendental*. Let $g(0,0)=a$, $g(0,1)=b$, $g(1,0)=c$, $g(1,1)=d$. Here $a,b,c,d$ only take on values $0$ and $1$. The corresponding probabilities are $(1-p)^2, p(1-p), p(1-p),p^2$. There are two ways the sum of $1$, $2$, or $3$ of these probabilities is $p$:

(i) $X_1=1, X_2=0$ or $X_1=1, X_2=1$. This is the projection onto the first coordinate.

(i) $X_1=0, X_2=1$ or $X_1=1, X_2=1$. This is the projection onto the second coordinate.

Comment: Thank you. Nice example.  Do you have any other thougts on this problem. Maybe we restric our attention to exponential distriubutions like $f_X \sim e^{-|x|^k}$ something can be said.

Comment: @Boby: Exponential is interesting, to add to your positive non-trivial examples. Let $X$ be exponential. Let $g(x_1,x_2)=\min(x_1,x_2)$.  Since $\min(X_1,X_2)$ is exponential,  by multiplying by $2$ we get an exponential with the same distribution as $X$.

Comment: It would be interesting to find such transformation for each $k$.    Right now we have that for $k=1$ we have $g=min(\cdot ,\cdot  )$ and  for $k=2$ we get $g= \cdot + \cdot$.  But I don't see the pattern yet. Anyway, please let me know if you have any thoughts.

Comment: I was thinking of the usual "positive" exponential. But maybe your $ce^{-|x|^k}$ can be dealt with.

Comment: I posted this question  here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1840386/transformation-of-two-laplace-distributions-that-results-in-a-laplace-distributi  to generate a few more examples.

Comment: Why Do you require $p$ to be trascendental?